# Chrome Extension: How do I get me Content Script Extension to show up on select websites

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I would like my Chrome Extension to on show up on google and amazon. My manifest.json looks like this:

```
{
 "background": {"scripts": ["background.js"]},
 "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.google.com/*", "http://www.amazon.com/*", "*://*.amazon.com/*"],
      "js": ["background.js"]
    }
  ],
 "name": "Denver Public Library Lookup",
 "description": "Does Stuff",
 "homepage_url": "http://www.artifacting.com",
 "icons": {
     "16": "icon-16.png",
     "48": "icon-48.png",
     "128": "icon-128.png" },
 "permissions": [
     "tabs",
     "http://*/*",
     "https://*/*"
 ],
 "version": "1.0",
 "manifest_version": 2
}
```

But it doesn't show up on either google or amazon and I can't figure out why.

Here is my background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "bookmarklet.js"})
});
```

And here is the bookmarlet.js

```
setTimeout('x99.focus()', 300);
var re = /([\/-]|at[at]n=)/i;
if (re.test(location.href) == true) {
    var isbn = RegExp.$2;
    var x99 = window.open('http://searchsite/search/searchresults.aspx?ctx=1.1033.0.0.6&type=Keyword&term=' + atatn, 'Library', 'scrollbars=1,resizable=1,top=0,left=0,location=1,width=800,height=600');
    x99.focus();
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks for your help.

Comment: See developer tools what say? http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many mistakes in the code.

- You don't need content script here, all operations could be executed
  within background page content
- It it hard to make background page
  code works within content script, this is definitely not a your case.
  So using the same background.js as both background and content script
  does not work in your case at least
- Manifest does not declare browser
  action.
- And so on

I strongly suggest to start with [Google extension documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html). You will save a lot of your time.

How I think files might look like

manifest.json

```
{
 "background": {"scripts": ["background.js"]},
 "name": "Denver Public Library Lookup",
 "description": "Does Stuff",
 "homepage_url": "http://www.artifacting.com",
 "icons": {
     "16": "icon-16.png",
     "48": "icon-48.png",
     "128": "icon-128.png" },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "19": "images/icon-19.png",
      "38": "images/icon-38.png"
    },
    "default_title": "Do Staff"      // optional; shown in tooltip
  },
 "permissions": [
     "tabs",
     "http://*/*",
     "https://*/*"
 ],
 "version": "1.0",
 "manifest_version": 2
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  // You need more sothisticated regexp here which checks for amazon and google domains
  var re = /([\/-]|at[at]n=)/i;
  if (re.test(tab.url)) {
    var isbn = RegExp.$2;
    var url = "http://searchsite/search/searchresults.aspx?ctx=1.1033.0.0.6&type=Keyword&term=" + isbn;
    chrome.windows.create({
      url : url, 
      left: 0,
      top: 0,
      width: 800,
      height: 600,
      focused: true,
      type: "popup"
    });
  }
});
```

bookmarlet.js is not needed

Comment: Thanks again for the help Andreyl. After following the link to the documentation I saw that this http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction.html is what I was trying to do.

Comment: Yes, it better suits for your needs. But 1) you need to add code to show it for specific pages (e.g. when ISDN appears), 2) sample code is simpler with browser actions

Comment: Also could you accept the answers if you think they are correct please?

Comment: The problem with browser actions is that the icon always show in the browser and I really only want it to show for on a few specific pages.